# How do I add Firebase app Distribution in-app feedback to a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, feedback, firebase-app-distribution

I have built a flutter app which I am sharing to users via Firebase App Distribution. I would like to take advantage of the tester feedback of the App Distribution, however, I cannot seem to find a way to implement it for flutter.

The documentation is only about android, via kotlin and Java, but no flutter. Does anyone know how to implement it in flutter? Link to documentation[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/collect-feedback-from-testers?hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*19tv9xd*_ga*MTQ5MTE3MDE5OS4xNjk2NjA2Njky*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcwMjA2ODg2Mi4xMDEuMS4xNzAyMDcwMzk5LjYwLjAuMA..#kotlin+ktx).